# MySQL: Return all rows of table A and true|false if record exists in table B

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a sales_cat table, and a user_cat table.

**sales_cat**

- id_cat
- name

**user_cat**

- id
- id_user
- id_cat

I need to get all the sales_cat rows, joined with the user_cat table for a specific user, indicating if that user has or not the category. Example, for id_user = 4 it should return:

```
id_cat | name  | selected
1      | kids  | 1
2      | men   | 1
3      | women | 0
```

Of course, the "selected" field is actually a value that depends on the existence of a linked record in user_cat. I've set a table structure in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/395ba).

My current solution only returns the linked data:

```
SELECT sales_cat.id_cat, sales_cat.name
FROM sales_cat
LEFT JOIN user_cat ON user_cat.id_cat = sales_cat.id_cat
WHERE user_cat.id_user = 4
```

...which is returning:

```
id_cat | name
1      | kids
2      | men
```

I'm still missing the "selected" column and the **3 | women** row.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to happen so rarely that I have to say; great question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Like This

```
SELECT sales_cat.id_cat, sales_cat.name,case when
user_cat.id is null then 0 else 1 end as "selected" FROM 
sales_cat LEFT JOIN user_cat ON 
user_cat.id_cat = sales_cat.id_cat and 
user_cat.id_user = 4
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/395ba/25 Thanks @Phil

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select distinct 
s.id_cat, 
s.name, 
case when u.id_user is null then 0 else 1 end selected
from sales_cat s
left join user_cat u on s.id_cat = u.id_cat 
and (u.id_user = 4 or u.id_user is null)
```

While the approach is similar to Satson's answer, we move the null check from `user_cat` to `id_user`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

SELECT sales_cat.id_cat, sales_cat.name, case when user_cat.id_user is not null then 1 else 0 end selected
FROM sales_cat
LEFT JOIN user_cat ON (user_cat.id_cat = sales_cat.id_cat and user_cat.id_user = 4)